# Apple push notification not working with aps_production.cer

Tags: objective-c, ios8, xcode6

I added push notification to my iOS application. Currently my app is in app store. it receives push notification whilst using `aps_development.cer` with it's corresponding `.p12` file but it's not receiving notification using `aps_production.cer`... I'm using `simplepush.php` to send push notification with reference of [link]:http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1

please help me out.... thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

The script is using `gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195` APNS server which is suitable for development.

For production, use APNS at `gateway.push.apple.com:2195`

Comment: i changed this too. but still it's not receiving notifications

Comment: how check my app is shipped with aps_production.cer?

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your .p12 file into .pem file first.